# Why I can't access native UINavigationBar from ActionBar?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I was trying to access and didn't find the UINavigationBar from an ActionBar, could someone help me there?

### TS file

```
let bar: ActionBar = this.page.getViewById<ActionBar>("bar");
bar.ios.nativeView // undefined
bar.nativeView // undefined
```

### HTML file

```
<ActionBar id="bar" class="action-bar" title="Recipients"></ActionBar>
```

Comment: When exactly you are trying to access the `nativeView`? It should be available in the loaded event.

Comment: @Manoj I'm trying on these events - ngAfterViewInit, ngOnInit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figure out what i've done wrong just putting in Manoj Solution

### HTML:

```
<ActionBar id="bar" class="action-bar" title="Recipients" (loaded)="loadActionBar($event)"></ActionBar>
```

### TS:

```
loadActionBar($event): void {
   let bar: ActionBar = this.page.getViewById<ActionBar>("bar");
   bar.nativeView // works
}
```